# Calculate value / evaluate Series @ infinity

Tags: sequences-and-series

I got this on my quiz yesterday it was the only thing that i could not solve.

We were asked to evaluate the following series:

$$ \sum_{n = 2}^{\infty}  7 * \frac{-5^{n}}{2^{3n-2}}
$$

Comment: Do you want $2^{3n-2}$ in the denominator? I imagine this is what was intended.

Comment: Can you write this as a "geometric series"?  Is "geometric series" a topic in your course?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you have $(-5)^n$ upstairs in the sum.

Try to write the terms of this Geometric series in standard form:

$$


7\cdot{ (-5)^n\over 2^{3n-2}} = 
7\cdot{ (-5)^n\over2^{-2} 2^{3n } }

 = {4\cdot 7}\cdot{ (-5)^n\over  ({2^3})^{ n }}
={28}\cdot{ \Bigl({-5\over 8}\Bigr)^{ n }}.

$$

Then
$$
\sum_{n=2}^\infty 
7\cdot{ (-5)^n\over 2^{3n-2} } = 
\sum_{n=2}^\infty
{28}\cdot{ \Bigl({-5\over 8}\Bigr)^{ n }}
={28}\cdot {(-5/8)^2\over 1-(-5/8)}
={28}\cdot{25/64\over 13/8   }
={28}\cdot{25\over 13\cdot8 }
={{25\cdot 7\over 13\cdot 2}}.
 
$$

(The sum of a convergent Geometric series is the first term divided by (1- ratio)).

Comment: you sir are a genius, +1 for a very direct and simple explanation

Comment: @kellax Thanks, but it's not true.. eventually, I'll edit out all the arithmetic mistakes :)